# Changing system hostname makes samba being unaccessible

Tags: debian, samba, firewall, hostname

I found something weird in my debian 9 config.

I changed my hostname by editing /etc/hostname and rebooting from "myhost" to "myhost-hello".

Since this modification connecting to the machine via it's ip (I don't use WINS or other functions like that at all) shows the server not reacheable.

I said myself.. maybe it's some kind of firewall issue, so I directly connected to the machine but the machine was still not reacheable via smb:// from an ubuntu test pc.

I tried to reboot the samba daemon various times with any success..

When I switched the hostname of the target machine back to "myhost" samba returned available.

I wonder.. is there some kind of automatic configuration of the hostname that makes samba not reacheable if the hostname changes? (note again that I connect to that machine via it's ip, and I don't use the wins feature or try to connect to it via it's hostname)

Comment: You might need to change `server string` under `/etc/samba/smb.conf` too

Comment: @Achu I can't find that setting inside the config file.. :( should I declare it explicitly ? but in that case why changing hostname makes it not reacheable ?

Comment: @Achu I found it inside the smb.conf manual.. it says that it just changes the comment about the smb server.. it seems unrelated to my problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the error got solved editing also the /etc/hosts making the machine able to understand that the hostname must be searched locally instead being passed via the default gateway.

So.. TL;DR:

/etc/hosts

edit the line

`myhost 127.0.0.1` for example to

`myhost-hello 127.0.0.1`

... that's all